# HTTP Error 500.19 with Error Code 0x8007000d visual studio 2017 while deploying .net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created default .net core application using visual studio 2017 and am trying to publish it, The application works perfectly when I start it with visual studio 2017, IIS Express. But when I publish the application I get the following error:
[image]

I use somee.com free hosting.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 30):

Usually this error indicates that the ASP.NET Core Module is not installed on the server. Hosting ASP.NET Core application on IIS requires Microsoft ASP.NET Core Module. You should confirm that the module has been installed. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle)

Comment: TLDR: Go there https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all then select .NET Core/Runtime/TheMostRecent then download and install: Windows/Server Hosting Installer

Comment: I don't know why, but in my case it was already installed and I had to repair the ASP.NET Core Module. Thank you regnauld

Answer (score 8):

Installing IIS URL Rewrite (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) helped me in this case.

Comment: Yep, this. All this.

Comment: Yes indeed, this did it for me, I don't understand it tho!  I tried all the above suggestions but it didn't fully resolve until installing IIS URL Rewrite.

Comment: That's because you have `rewrite` tag in your `web.config` file. In fact, any IIS OOB component can lead to such 500.19 + 0x8007000d error.

Answer (score 6):

Reinstall .NET core or do a repair. It worked for me.
This happens when you first install .NET core before IIS.

Comment: Doing a repair for both the .Net Core Runtime and the hosting bundle worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Installing .NET Core hosting bundle with respect to my .NET Core release version worked for me.

For .NET Core 2.2 you can visit [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2)

Or you can select other versions [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error on Windows 10, and I had to install the [Core Hosting Bundle](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting).

**Note to Microsoft**: If I'm installing the [SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2), *maybe* I need the hosting bundle too.

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rohithrajan/2018/03/13/500-19-error-or-502-5-error-when-hosting-asp-net-core-2-application-inside-iis/)