# HTTP 500.19-Internal Server Error. without any config Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, hosting, server-error

I am trying to host a asp.net mvc web application on iis but having this error  [image]

Now the problem is that it does not have any error in the Config Error: section. I have given the permission to the folder for IIS_IUSERS but still no success. I have almost every solution I come accross on internet, but nothing is solving my problem. My config file is this

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CECDashboard.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have also tried changing DefaultAppPool .NET CLR from v4.0.30319 to v2.0.50727 but still no success.

I have also tried pass-through authentication and specific user but both with the same results (no success)

Please suggest me something. I will be very thankful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 500.19 with Error Code 0x8007000d visual studio 2017 while deploying .net core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889736/http-error-500-19-with-error-code-0x8007000d-visual-studio-2017-while-deploying)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not an `Asp.Net Core` application, just Asp.net framework `MVC` application.
Asp.Net application requires certain windows feature to run it. please enable the `Asp.Net`feature in the windows features.
[image]
If the web application is indeed a `DotNet Core MVC` application, please consider installing Asp.net Core Hosting Bundle, which includes the `DotNet Core Runtime` and `IIS` support.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/current/runtime
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tryied both the asp.net framework web app and asp.net core web app. both are giving me the same problem. Moreover I had alread enabled ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.5, It is not showing me option for ASP.NET 4.8.

Comment: Please tell me more details about your issue. Which version is your current server’s OS? Which type is the web application? Asp.Net4.8 is a highly compatible, in-place update to the older Microsoft .NET Framework version, which can provide runtime support for Asp.Net web application.
Here is a download address.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4503548/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am using Windows 8.1 and the web application is on .net core 2.2.

Comment: I have no idea. On my side, I once ran into this problem.  As long as I installed ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle, the Http 500.19 error disappeared. 
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-2.2.8-windows-hosting-bundle-installer